# compute conjugacy classes of matrices over $\mathcal{Z}$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, arithmetic-geometry

Given an irreducible polynomial $f(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, do you know an efficient algorithm to compute the number of conjugacy classes of matrices $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with characteristic polynomial $f$?

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the number of ideal classes of ideals $I$ in the ring ${\bf Z}[\lambda,\lambda^{-1}]$   where we can choose $\lambda $ to be any of the roots, such that the endomorphism ring of $I$ (as a ${\bf Z}[\lambda,\lambda^{-1}]$-module) is no larger than ${\bf Z}[\lambda,\lambda^{-1}]$. I don't know if this is helpful.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of something else. Just the ideal classes in ${\bf Z}[\lambda]$ of ideals whose endomorphism ring is no larger than ${\bf Z}[\lambda]$.

Comment: Dammit, I'll get this right eventually. Forget the endo ring (the endomorphism rings are inside the integral closure and are invariants for the ideal classes anyway). This goes back to the 1920s.

Comment: Yes @DavidHandelman, this is a related question to abelian varieties over finite fields whose endomorphism algebra is a field. It's just that I've seen examples for polynomials of degree 4 but I don't know how to calculate for others examples.